# Why does my Featherlight gallery needs two clicks to be activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce, featherlight.js

My Featherlight gallery needs two clicks to be activated.
Would you happen to know why?
Here is my code...

Javascript/jQuery:

```
    $(".woocommerce-product-gallery").attr({
    "data-featherlight-gallery" : "",
    "data-featherlight-filter" : "a"
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery">
    <figure class="product_gallery">
        <div data-thumb="THUMBNAIL_image.jpg" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="BIG_image.jpg"><img width="593" height="800" src="MEDIUM_image.jpg" data-src="BIG_image.jpg"></a></div>
        <div data-thumb="THUMBNAIL_image2.jpg" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="BIG_image2.jpg"><img width="593" height="800" src="MEDIUM_image2.jpg"></a></div>
        <div data-thumb="THUMBNAIL_image3.jpg" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="BIG_image3.jpg"><img width="593" height="800" src="MEDIUM_image3.jpg"></a></div>
</figure>
```

I can't get rid of the container as they are part of Woocommerce plugin dynamics.

Here is the example: http://jadepalacecollective.com/product/shoes-4/
Click on the shoes once... and then twice. See?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript console shows this error:

> "Featherlight: no content filter found  (no target specified)"

This error usually happens when you add images to Featherlight after binding it. To prevent this error you can manually bind Featherlight after dynamically adding your images:

```
$('woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper').featherlight();
```

Comment: Hi Geraldo. that exact line didn't solve it... but you were on the right train of thought. This is what ended up working (by placing this after setting the featherlight attributes):



$('.woocommerce-product-gallery').featherlightGallery();  

I will mark you answer as correct. Many thanks!

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Answer (score -2):

The first click doesn't work because of this error:

> Featherlight: no content filter found  (no target specified)

line 227 of featherlight.js

You can check your browser console after the first click on the gallery, you should see the same error